# conversion blue j program to jar file

Tags: javascript, bluej

How can I convert my PROGRAM  to jar or exe
it is a simple program

public class Hello
{

public static void main( String[]  a )
{

```
System .out. print ln ( "Hello, World!" );
```

}

}

java

Answer (score 0):

### To convert your program to jar or exe on BlueJ ide(v 5.0.1)

### Follow the steps below:

**STEP 1:** Open the project containing the programs files you want to convert into jar files.

**STEP 2:** Click on the 'Project' option in the toolbar. Then choose the 'Create Jar File' option.
[To Find option see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUlUu.jpg)

**STEP 3:** A dialog box will appear choose file and then click on 'continue'. Then enter the file name and choose the location of the file where you want to save it. Then click on 'save'.

**NOTE:** IF YOU HAVE MORE THAN ONE FILE IN YOUR PROJECT THEN YOUR ALL FILES MUST BE COMPILED OTHERWISE YOU A WARNING MESSAGE WILL POP UP.